# Can I write Java code that uses Monkeyrunner?

Tags: java, android, monkeyrunner

Instead of writing Python code that runs through the Jython interpreter, as suggested by Google, I'd like to write Java code that deals directly with the Monkeyrunner.jar and friend.

My biggest motivation for doing this is that I will be able to catch Java exceptions this way, and I am not able to do so using Python. Monkeyrunner throws many exceptions (mostly socket errors) when run for a long time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

You can include `chimpchat.jar` in your java build path plus some other dependencies (e.g. `ddmlib.jar, sdklib.jar. guavalib.jar`) and then

```
mChimpchat = ChimpChat.getInstance(options);
mDevice = mChimpchat.waitForConnection();
```